# itext filling table

Tags: java, itext

I need to fill a table with in the first column a number and in the second column certain data from a array.

So it will look like :

1  |  Data1

2  |  Data2

3  |  Data3

What is the best way to add this data.

Usualy you do something like :

```
 Table table = new Table(3); 
 table.setWidth(100);           
 table.setDefaultVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);           
 table.setCellsFitPage(true);            
 table.setPadding(2);            
 table.setSpacing(0);              
 for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {            
 Cell cell = new Cell("Data " + i);            
 table.addCell(cell); }
```

Then you get something like :

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

Data 4 | Data 5 | Data 6

Is there a specific way to fill selected cells or do I see it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table table = new Table( 2 ); // 2 is the number of columns

table.setWidth( 100 );
table.setDefaultVerticalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_TOP ) ;
table.setCellsFitPage( true );
table.setPadding( 2 );
table.setSpacing( 0 );

for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++ )
{
     Cell leftCell = new Cell( i );
     Cell rightCell = new Cell( "Data " + i );

     table.addCell( leftCell );
     table.addCell( rightCell );
}
```

Comment: that's only his first problem he also has to do the row thing too.

Comment: you should only go to 3 in the loop

Comment: Yea, the colums aren't the problem.  This is a simple solution that works!  But is ther a way to add certain data in certain table fields.  Like this way you need to fill the table in the right order.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to fill the table sequentially. I haven't tried it, but maybe you can define a cell in the table, and then later change the text in the cell before the pdf is rendered, again, i'm not sure without trying.

Comment: @DarthBlueRay Where is the Table class defined I can only find JTable in the Java SE 6 documentation?

Comment: @twain249 itext issue-> import com.lowagie.text.Table;

Comment: @DarthBlueRay There's an `addCell` that takes in a `Point location` along with the data I'd reckon that it's used to add to a certain cell.

Comment: @DarthBlueRay there's also an `addCell` that takes in two `ints` `row` and `column` use that to specify the location to add the cell.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote : the Table class can be found in rather old versions of iText that are not supported anymore. Most recent versions make use of PdfPTable.

I warmly recommend you to upgrade to a more recent version in order to get all the latest features, bug fixes and security fixes.