# table.addCell (cell) using itext pdfptable scroll vertically instead of horizontally on the table

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

I get a list of the column items. When I add the items separately in a repeating loop to a cell. The column data is displayed online. Is there any way for the inclusion of addCell data (cell) occurs vertically (by columns) and not horizontally (by rows)?

This solution not applicable-> [itext filling table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181284/itext-filling-table)

**IMPORTANT  (CHANGE) :**
PS: I modified the DataSet class to be compatible with the itext behavior because I did not find an implementation for my problem. It worked, but was not visually pleasing. For this reason I decided not to use more tables and cells to display the information in the report. I'm using the PDFWriter itext to print the DataSet values ​​diretamnte on the screen. but I have not found an implementation to fetch values ​​from an array of an object which in turn each object d this array has a Arraylit string. I can fetch the value of the entire row, ie the String Array once, using the iterator. how do I get individual values? because there is always incompatible with the types that sound itext accepted into the library, either with the "Paragraph" or "Chuck" attribute. So this review of the link is the closest example of what I found. I get the values ​​of a line iteira accessing the RowReport. But when I try to access an element of this line with the RowData there error:

```
List<Row> RowReport;

Class Row{
    ArrayList<String> rowData;
}
```

---

```
List items ds.getData = ();

ArrayList <Row> = al ds.getData ();

Iterator <Row> itr = al.iterator ();

// Runs through lines
while (itr.hasNext ()) {
  Row element = itr.next ();

  // traverses the line items
  for (int i = 0; i <numeroColunas; i ++) {

    // column name
    Paragraph p = new paragraph ();
    p.add (columns [i] .getName ());
    // items
    //String cde = itens.get (i) .toString (); // ERROR
    //String cde = itens.get (i); // ERROR
    // p.add ((com.itextpdf.text.Element) itens.get (i)); // ERROR
```

Comment: How would iText know when a column ends? Your requirement doesn't match the design of tables in iText, hence you have to create a workaround that stores the cells in an m x n matrix first, and then add the cells to the `PdfPTable` (**NOT** `Table`) in the order that is expected by iText.

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I found that the implementation of itext pulls by lines and not by columns. the solution was to modify the DataSet to bring one Arrays list by rows rather than by columns.

Comment: Hello Bruno. Where do I find examples for reporting without tables, common one line at a time using DataSet and not ResultSet? I will look at examples of page iText, but only encounter examples with resultSet. I plan to use a DataSet object that is a list of Strings Arrays. Example: List <Array> MyDataSeth

Comment: That question has already been answered in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404686/i-need-to-create-a-table-and-assign-the-values-into-the-table-in-pdf-using-javaf)

Comment: I find this page: "http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/XfaForm.html#findDatasetsNode(java.lang.String)" But the methods don't function in my program. :-(

Comment: I don't understand why you're talking about XFA when your question is about creating a table with cells. Why would you use the `XfaForm` class? How does that make sense?

Comment: I altered the way to bring the data because I was finding it very difficult, and the use of XFA was the closest of what I got. I changed the description of the question

Comment: How to print the object type on the screen using the itext?
I'm trying to PdfWriter. But it's not working.
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.PdfBody.html

Comment: What is the object type? Why are you saying you want to print something to the screen with iText? iText *doesn't write anything to the screen.* iText *creates PDF!* Why are you referring to an internal class `PdfBody` that is to be used internally by `PdfWriter` only? Are you making fun of me? I will leave this conversation. Your questions make no sense. You should read the documentation first. You shouldn't pretend you've read the documentation by linking to API docs that are completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear. In fact, Screen is way of speaking, because the pdf press the browser. I know who writes the pdf file. See, the object does not have a defined type because it is a generic method.
It is as follows:

For Case, carries an Array of Strings. But is set objetc ow it is for a generic report. private ArrayList RowData;

  And the call:

ValorCelulaRow = iteratorRow.next Object ();

if (valorCelulaRow! = null) {

     Paragraph p = new paragraph ();
     p.add ((com.itextpdf.text.Element) valorCelulaRow);

Comment: I used the PDFBody was a reference to a more abstract object next I found. I know different. I know the documentation and API are different. But I found what I needed in the documentation, so I'm looking at the API.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Have to make another implementation of itarator within the Row class. And this time the "toString ()" worked without problems. Now, there is no error. Thank you Bruno, sorry the disorder because he had urgent need to seek the solution of this problem. I am very grateful for the help.